# Android BottomNavigationView react to SlidingUpPanelLayout mouvements

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I've been trying to animate some BottomNavigationView depdending on com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout mouvements.
here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidingUpPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.test.activity.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        app:umanoPanelHeight="50dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/invitationFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.test.fragment.CustomListFragment" />
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_bottom_bar_bg"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/item_bottom_bar_bg"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also been trying to incorporate a CoordinatorLayout as top view together with BottomNavigationViewBehavior extending CoordinatorLayout.Behavior but without success.

I have also been tryin to listen to events on the panel (slidingUpPanelLayout.setOnScrollChangeListener & slidingUpPanelLayout.setOnDragListener) but strangly they never get called.

I am using the following versions :

- android support lib 25.3.1
- com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0

The idea is to have the exact same behaviour of the bottom bar as in soundcloud app. (and soundcloud is using com.sothree.slidinguppanel lib).

Thank you.

Comment: Y don't you use Bottom sheet?  which is having the same features I think.

Comment: thank you for the advice, i've been able to use BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback.onSlide in order to slideDown my BottomNavigation View.

Comment: Happy to hear that helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally used BottomSheetBehavior + its callback to animate the BotomNavigationBar.
here is the layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/light_grey"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp">
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/invitationFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:name="com.test.view.fragment.InvitationListFragment" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_bottom_bar_bg"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/item_bottom_bar_bg"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the related code:
I had the possibility to use a customBehaviour extending BottomSheetBehavior or simply listen to BottomSheetCallback, i went for the 2nd solution:

callback :

```
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            slideDown(bottomNavigationView,slideOffset);
        }
    });
```

smooth animation (the BottomNavigationBar goes down while scrolling the BottomSheet up and vice versa):

```
    private void slideDown(BottomNavigationView child, float slideOffset) {
    float heigh_to_animate = slideOffset * child.getHeight();
    ViewPropertyAnimator animator = child.animate();
    animator
            .translationY(heigh_to_animate)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
            .setDuration(0)
            .start();
}
```

Comment: it keeps the blank space in bottom after animation which looks weird.... how did you fix that ?