# SlidingPanelUp behaviour with BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How is it possible to achieve this behaviour with umano sliding panel and a bottom navigation view sliding on top of eachother?

Since Umano Sliding Panel up requires 2 child layouts(main layout and slider layout) where should i add the navigation view? At the moment my layout is like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>

     <SlidingPanelUp layout_above="bottom_navigation_view">

     <(Main)CoordinatorLayout>
     <(Slider)LinearLayout/>
     <(Main)/CoordinatorLayout>

     </SlidingPanelUp>

<BottomNavigationView alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now when the slider takes up all of the screen i have to hide the bottom navigation and when slider is collapsed or closed i have to make navigation visible again.

The problem is that i use "setVisibility" method on the navigation bar and it just appears and disappears out of nowhere and the transition is really ugly.

I tried using animations but the sliding animation from the SlidingPanel is faster than my custom animation so the navigation always ends up on top (basically the 'layout_above="bottom_navigation_view"' is not working).

Any idea how to make it as smooth as SoundCloud?

Comment: Why not the standard [BottomSheetBehavior](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md) ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti saw it a little too late ,but still Umano's SlidingPanel seems to work kinda the same.

Comment: Yes, but the last commit was 2 years ago, while the Material Components is developed by Google team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i did like @Gabriele Mariotti said and implemented a [BottomSheetBehavior](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md).
For the SoundCloud like animation i used: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965107/android-bottomnavigationview-react-to-slidinguppanellayout-mouvements).

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have time to create an example for you, but have a look at [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout). Basically you define 2 constraint sets in xml: the first scene positions everything like in the starting screen and the second scene positinos everything like after sliding up the panel. Then you use the onSwipe tag (also in the scene-xml) to define the up-down movement and what View should be sensitive for this sliding action.

More detailed information can be found here: https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-i-29208674b10d

It's a long blog post, but worth the read, since this new Layout is really really powerful and fairly easy to use.